# Launching JMeter from LoadRunner with correct HEAP size

Tags: jmeter, heap-memory, loadrunner

I am able to launch JMeter scripts from LoadRunner - but many of the threads getting stack because of out of Memory. I can configure jmeter.bat to use correct HEAP size, but it will only be helpful if I run JMeter script from GUI or Command Line mode. LoadRunner always launches JMeter with default parameters of 512m for minimum and maximum HEAP size, and I have no idea of where to change that value in LoadRunner 2020 SP3 (which is the latest version of LoadRunner which allows running unlimited number of JMeter VUsers). Anyone any experience of running thousands of JMeter VUsers from LoadRunner controller and how to set HEAP size that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not just add another load generator?